# Compare two date values not time in php

Tags: php

I am using this script to compare two date columns in php . I have folder with images and want to merge all the images acccording to their date into one xml. image format is "entry_145_BD12ZZU_2014-06-25_12-26-58".jpg

```
 if(file_exists($xmlFullFilename)) {
if($entryTimeNode->format("Y-m-d") = $entryTimeNode->format("Y-m-d"))** this is what I tried.
            $xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
            $tmp = split(" ", $entryTime);
        $dateString = $tmp[0] . "T" . $tmp[1];
        $entryTimeNode = $xmlDoc->createElement("EntryTime", $dateString);
```

**XML FILE**

```
    <Incidents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Count="2" Date="2014-10-24" Time="12:05:39" FileName="2014-10-24_Brook_Retail_Park.xml">
      <Incident>
      <EntryTime>**2014-10-17**T11:17:44</EntryTime>
      </Incident>
    <Incident>
<EntryTime>**2014-10-17**T16:19:15</EntryTime>
</Incident></Incidents>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by all the code in this question. How does it relate to your problem of comparing two dates? Are you able to read the values from the file? If so, the only problem that remains is, *"I have two strings (read from an XML file), say `'**2014-10-17**T11:17:44'` and `'**2014-10-17**T16:19:15'`. I want to compare them using only the date part (without time). I already tried ...."*

Comment: Hi Golez,I just need to merge all files with same date into one xml file.

Comment: Still not clear what the problem is. Are you stuck on comparing, on merging ... Please narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Yes I need to comapare them  but dont know how to comapre them.sorry for bad english

Comment: So basically all the provided code is mostly irrelevant?

Comment: I have deleted all the code except the datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

```
mostly date also compare with as like normal variable like: 

$a=5;
$b=10;
if($a > $b){
 //Blalala
}

and in date also you can compare like this
$c=2014/10/29;
$d=2014/10/29;
if($c > $d){
 //Blalala
}

and i can't more figure out from question you have date with time so in your case,
$e=**2014-10-17**T11:17:44
$f=**2014-10-17**T16:19:15

$first_date_ary=explode("**", $e);
$second_date_ary=explode("**", $f);

and then compare your date, as per i mention above
if($first_date_ary[0] > $second_date_ary[0]){
 //Blalala
}

and sorry for bad English too.
```